# d3 version 4 rescaleX where X scale is scaleTime

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When i call rescaleX on a time scale the returned scale has a domain of invalid dates. Is it possible to zoom time scales with version 4 of d3?

I have produced a simple JSBIN to demonstrate the issue. Please zoom using your mousewheel on the dark grey rectangle and observe the console (your browser console as JSBIN can't print out invalid dates properly!).

https://jsbin.com/nucasireva/edit?html,js,output

```js
const container = d3.select('.app')

const data = [{
    x: '2015-05-12',
    v: 12
  },
  {
    x: '2015-05-13',
    v: 13
  },
  {
    x: '2015-05-14',
    v: 15
  },
  {
    x: '2015-05-15',
    v: 16
  }
]

const formattedData = data.map(d => ({
  x: new Date(d.x),
  v: d.v
}))

const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, 500]).domain(formattedData, d => d.x)

const zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
  const newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)
  console.log(newX.domain(), newX.domain()[1])
})


zoom(container)
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<div class='app' style='background: grey;width:500px;height:300px;'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it is. (this is not only a correct answer but the only possible answer to your question, which doesn't have any code)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i have provided a jsbin please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is simply the domain of your scale: the domain has to be an array with 2 elements, the minimum and the maximum.

That being said, just change:

```
const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, 500])
    .domain(formattedData, d => d.x);
```

To:

```
const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, 500])
    .domain(d3.extent(formattedData, d => d.x));
```

`d3.extent` will return an array with the maximum and minimum value in `formattedData`, using that accessor function.

Here is your working code:

```js
const container = d3.select('.app')

const data = [{
  x: '2015-05-12',
  v: 12
}, {
  x: '2015-05-13',
  v: 13
}, {
  x: '2015-05-14',
  v: 15
}, {
  x: '2015-05-15',
  v: 16
}]

const formattedData = data.map(d => ({
  x: new Date(d.x),
  v: d.v
}))

const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, 500]).domain(d3.extent(formattedData, d => d.x));

const zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
  const newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)
  console.log(newX.domain(), newX.domain()[1])
})

zoom(container)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 22% !important;}
```

```html
<div class='app' style='background: grey;width:500px;height:300px;'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep - Forgot got to use d3.extent.